# Existe algum comando para listar todas as chaves estrangeiras de uma tabela MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

Gostaria de saber como faço para listar todas as foreign keys existentes em uma tabela específica.

Por exemplo:

```
 usuarios [id, nome, nivel_id*, empresa_id*, cargo_id*]
```

No caso acima, listaria os campos `empresa_id`, `nivel_id` e `cargo_id` com suas respectivas informações.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para cada instância do `MySql` existe um banco de dados chamado `information_schema`. Neste banco contém todas as informações de todos os bancos de dados da instância.

Para recuperar todas as chaves estrangeiras, basta fazer um `SELECT` na tabela `REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.`REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS`;
```

Se quiser filtrar as chaves estrangeiras de uma tabela específica, adicione a clausula `WHERE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.`REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS` a
WHERE a.`CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA` = 'nome_do_banco' AND a.`TABLE_NAME` = 'nome_da_tabela'
```

Existem muitas outras coisas úteis neste banco de dados, [veja a documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema.html).

Comment: Bacana +1.......